# Only accept Integer values from InputBox VB.Net within Do While Loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to figure out why my program is accepting non-integer values which it then converts to an integer by rounding. The first value the user enters is validated, however, the rest isn't. My program is meant to count the number of odd and even integer numbers the user has entered. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddNum.Click
    Dim intInputNum As Integer
    Dim strInputNum As String = ""
    Dim isEven As Integer = 0
    Dim isOdd As Integer = 0
    Dim userInput As String = InputBox(("Enter a number (0 to end)"))
    Dim numArray() As String = strInputNum.Split(New Char() {","c})
    Dim validInput As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(userInput, intInputNum)


    If validInput = False Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input, integer numbers only")
    ElseIf validInput = True Then
        Do While intInputNum > 0 And validInput = True
            If intInputNum Mod 2 = 0 And validInput = True Then
                lblEvenValues.Text = lblEvenValues.Text & CStr(intInputNum) & ","
                intInputNum = Val(InputBox("Enter a number (0 to end)"))
                isEven = isEven + 1
                lblCountEven.Text = isEven
            ElseIf intInputNum Mod 2 <> 0 And validInput = True Then
                lblOddValues.Text = lblOddValues.Text & CStr(intInputNum) & ","
                intInputNum = Val(InputBox("Enter a number (0 to end)"))
                isOdd = isOdd + 1
                lblCountOdd.Text = isOdd
            ElseIf validInput = False Then
                MsgBox("Invalid input, integer numbers only")
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line:

`Do While intInputNum > 0`

is causing you issues. When the user inputs a non-integer value, after the first loop, this line: `Val(InputBox("Enter a number (0 to end)"))` evaluates to zero.
Which is obviously not greater than 0.

Reuse your boolean statement to evaluate userInput, not intInputNum like so:

`userInput = Val(InputBox("Enter a number (0 to end)"))
validInput = Integer.TryParse(userInput, intInputNum)`

Then you need to fix your message box location to simply show up outside of your loop rather than in it. So when `validInput <> True` it will break the loop and output your `Msgbox`.

You will also need to fix your `Do While` statement to correctly evaluate userInput instead of intInputNum

Comment: I strongly recommend not using Console.WriteLine (or Message Boxes) to debug. Visual Studio has a host of wonderful debugging tools starting with the break point where you can step through your code and see values of your variables. If you must, use Debug.Print. Then, if you forget to take it out when you release your program, the end user won't see your debugging.

Comment: @Mary Deleting my comment to make yours more visible. Didn't do my research on Console beforehand. It doesn't impact GUI applications nearly as hard, but you're right about using Debug.Print for the same purpose if you're going that route at all.